# Resource not found, which is declared in another XML files in Res > Values folder

Tags: android

Resource not found, which is declared in another XML files in Res > Values folder.

I've created an array of string called `questions.xml` in `Res > questions.xml` in which I've created  arrays of question and answers.

Those array's are populated while coding `R.array.questions`, but while running the code it throws an `ResourceNotFound` Exception, at that line.

Please give me solution.

Comment: When asking questions like this, it is best to include the XML files, the Java source code that is causing the error and the log output that shows the exception. Makes it MUCH easier to get a relevant/useful/timely/meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the android dev guide:

> res/values/filename.xml
>   The filename is arbitrary. The  element's name will be used as the resource ID.

Make sure your xml contains the string array named correctly. Follow the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="questions">
        <item>How do I create a string array?</item>
        <item>Will this work?</item>
        <item>Why didn't I paste the whole xml in the question?</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="answers">
        <item>Like this</item>
        <item>Yep</item>
        <item>No idea</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

You can save it with any name, such as `res/values/whatevername.xml` and you reference them in the code as `R.array.questions` and `R.array.answers`.

The official docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html